# Can't figure out what nodes to use to make this procedural texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I'll try to explain the best I can

I'm trying to build a texture, using an image as reference:[image]

I tried using this 3 combinations:

1. This was my final shot. From Sam Bowman - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ewq6e-HSWE
   My plan was to get the different directions and twists, but always having a "center" is bugging me a lot. also is not very similar

[image]

2. This was my base, because of the spiral effect. But it just had 1 center
   From OmarSquircleArt - https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-eevee-improvements-weekly-reports/7697
   [image]
3. I was hoping to make a Spiral in each "Division" of the texture, and be able to move the center of it. But got nothing close to what I want.
   From Blender Guru - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc&t=263s
   [image]

I tryied to combine the 3 methodes, but not with much luck

I understand enough of procedural textures, to know that I don't understand much. So I'm just giving random shots in the dark, searching google and youtube. And I was hopeing someone could point me in the right direction, on how to "Draw" the texture

The reason I wan't to use Procedural texture, is to make roughness and bump maps of it.
Thank you to everyone that will read this.